# Counting black pixels using Python

Tags: python, pixel

I am in my first programming class so very new.  I'm trying to count the black pixels in a picture and I'm stuck.    This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
#create a 10x10 black picture
 newPict = makeEmptyPicture(10, 10)
 show(newPict)
 setAllPixelsToAColor(newPict,black)
 #Display the picture
 show(newPict)
 #Initialize variabl countBlack to 0 
 countZero = 0
 for p in getPixels(newPict):
     r = getRed(p)
     b = getBlue(p)
     g = getGreen(p)
     if (r,g,b) == (0,0,0):
        countZero = countZero + 100
     return countZero
```

Comment: Correction "countZero = countZero +1"  not "100"

Comment: is `return countZero` inside or outside the `for` loop? Change it's indentation to move it outside the loop.

Comment: You need to de-dent the return statetement, because otherwise your main will return prematurely from within the for-loop

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

How it was pointed by kedar and deets , your return is INSIDE the for, so, in the first pixel it will return the value of countZero, instead of looping over all the image, just fixing the indention should be fine :

```
 for p in getPixels(newPict):
     r = getRed(p)
     b = getBlue(p)
     g = getGreen(p)
     if (r,g,b) == (0,0,0):
        countZero = countZero + 1
 return countZero
```